# Не выбираются поля из присоединяемой таблицы в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Хочу получить из БД записи с названиями категорий.
Пишу в моделе:

```
public static function getArticles()
{
    return Admin::find()
        ->select('my_articles.*, my_categories.name')
        ->from('my_articles')
        ->innerJoin('my_categories', 'my_articles.category_id = my_categories.id')
        ->limit(10)
        ->all();
}
```

Запрос правильный, в отладчике Yii показывает вот такой запрос:

SELECT `my_articles`.*, `my_categories`.`name` FROM `my_articles` INNER JOIN `my_categories` ON my_articles.category_id = my_categories.id LIMIT 10

Ввожу в phpmyadmin этот запрос, получается правильная таблица: таблица с статьями + названия категорий.
А когда я пытаюсь вывести название категории, то yii выбрасывает ошибку:

```
foreach ($articles as $article){
//...
echo $article->name;
}
```

Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
Getting unknown property: app\models\Admin::name

Comment: что выдает `print_r($articles)` ?

Comment: [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 7
                    [title] => Моя первая статья #7
                    [author] => LGP
                    [description] => Обычная статья
                    [pubdate] => 2017-11-05 21:07:31
                    [text] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...

                    [category_id] => 4
                    [active] => 1
                    [image] => 1.jpg
                    [views] => 8
                )
поля "name" нету

Comment: у тебя тут ACtiveRecord. а у него вроде innerJoinWith http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#innerJoinWith()-detail ......... а вот InnerJoin есть у Query  - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#innerJoin()-detail

Comment: хорошо, попробую, спасибо.

Comment: А не проще сделать обычным методом? `MyArticle::find()->with('myCategory')->all()` и потом просто в `foreach` категорию выводить как `echo $article->myCategory->name` ?